# AttributeError: module 'flax.linen' has no attribute 'transforms'

Tags: python, jax, flax

I received an error from flax 0.7.5, could u help me:

```
  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\jVMC\nets\__init__.py:5
    from jVMC.nets.rnn import *

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\jVMC\nets\rnn.py:92
    class RNN(nn.Module):

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\jVMC\nets\rnn.py:138 in RNN
    @partial(nn.transforms.scan,

AttributeError: module 'flax.linen' has no attribute 'transforms'
```

Many thanks!!!

I have tried flax 0.7.4
after I solved an `AttributeError: module 'flax' has no attribute 'nn'`

Answer (score 0):

From your traceback, it looks like you are using [vmc_jax](https://github.com/markusschmitt/vmc_jax). Looking at this package, it appears to require [flax v0.6.4-0.6.11](https://github.com/markusschmitt/vmc_jax/blob/v1.2.4/setup.py#L11); I suspect the error you're seeing is because you're using too new a flax version for this package.

I would suggest installing flax 0.6.11, and also use the required jax versions listed there:

```
$ pip install flax==0.6.11 jax==0.4.11 jaxlib==0.4.11
```